# How do I trace the data used to create the report?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using CR 9.  Sorry about that.

I have never used Crystal Reports; however, my boss has asked me to provide him the "logic" used in a report generated for one of our customers.  The report was created several years ago and the customer contact is new.  He wants to know what information we use to calculate the data reported in each column.  Is there an easy way to trace this information in Crystal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what version of CR you are using, so I'll make an assumption.  Run the report with any parameters that it may need.  From the file menu, click on "Database" and on the drop down menu, there should be an option to "Show SQL Query".

Comment: I got a box that said Enter Parameter Values @StartDate, @EndDate.  "AB-FtCollins"."dbo"."UDR_PlantConditionAssessmentScorecard";1 {ts '2009-02-20 11:11:59'}, {ts '2009-02-20 11:11:59'} - Is all that was returned.  Should I change a date?

Comment: What version of CR are you using?

Comment: Sounds like your report is calling a stored procedure. Also looks like your database is MSSQL; I would look at the source for the stored procedure to see what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you run the report, it'll ask you for the date info.  Then once it's done do the "show sql query" thing and it should fill in the dates for you in the query.